# Error in calculating sum of even place digits and odd place digits in java

Tags: java

In our directions, we have to get a 16 digit number, then sum all the digits in the odd place from right to left. After that, we have to sum all the even place digits from right to left, double the sum, then take module 9. When I try to run my code, I keep getting "Invalid", even if it is with a valid credit card number.

```
public static boolean validateCreditCard(long number) {
    double cardSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        long cardnumber = (long) Math.pow(10, i);
        double oddPlaceSum = 0;
        double evenPlaceSum = 0;
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            oddPlaceSum += ((int)(number % cardnumber / (Math.pow(10, i))));
        } else { // so if i%2 ==0
            evenPlaceSum += ((int)(number % cardnumber / (Math.pow(10, i)) * 2 % 9));
        }
        cardSum += evenPlaceSum + oddPlaceSum;
    }
    if (cardSum % 10 == 0) {
        return true;
        System.out.println("Valid");
    } else {
        return false;
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Java (unreachable statements).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

- Convert the 16 digit number into a String using    Long.toString(number).
- Iterate  through the String character by    character and keep track of even and odd indexes.
- Convert each char to an Integer using Integer.valueOf() thereby adding them    incrementally.
- Voila, you got your evenSum and oddSum. Next steps    should be trivial.

  ```
  public static boolean validateCreditCard(long number){
  String x = Long.toString(number);
  int evenSum = 0;
  int oddSum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<x.length; i=i+2) {
     oddSum += Integer.valueOf(s[i]);
     evenSum += Integer.valueOf(s[i+1]);
  }
  //Do the next steps with odd and even sums.
  ```

Also, do handle IndexOutOfBoundsException as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single while loop as digits are fixed, like this:

```
int digit,evensum,oddsum;
int i=16;
while(i > 0){
    digit=number%10;
    if(i%2 == 0)
         evensum+=digit;
    else
         oddsum+=digit;  
    i--;
    digit/=10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead
**using Recusion** find sum of even placed of digit and sum of odd placed of digit.

```java
class Recursion {
  static int count = 0;
  static int even =0;
  static int odd =0;
  public static int Digits(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
      count++;
      if(count%2 == 0){
          even += num%10;
      }
      else{
          odd += num%10;
      }
      Digits(num / 10);
    }
    return even;
    // for odd 
    // return odd;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 31593;
    int res = Digits(num);
    System.out.println("Total digits are: " + res);
  }
}
```

**Help me** How to print both even and odd sum together?